# Is there a way to find installed binary packages which don't have manpages?

Tags: debian, package-management, man

I recently saw https://lintian.debian.org/tags/binary-without-manpage.html and it shows around 14k manpages which are missing.

This means it's more than likely that some of the binary packages (not libraries) have missing manpages. How do I get a list of installed binary packages/applications (NOT libraries) which  don't have manpages? I might know some and start contributing a bit towards that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can list all binary without man page through `manpage-alert` command

```
manpage-alert - check for binaries without corresponding manpages

DESCRIPTION

   manpage-alert  searches the given list of paths for binaries without cor‐
   responding manpages.

   If no paths are specified on the command line, the path list  /bin  /sbin
   /usr/bin /usr/sbin /usr/games will be assumed
```

Comment: didn't know it was part of devscripts package, thanx.

Answer (score 5):

While `manpage-alert` does do what you ask for, you should note that the list in the link from your question is generated by a different process, which is the following check in Lintian:

https://github.com/Debian/lintian/blob/master/checks/manpages.pm

So it can be produced by calling `lintian` with the `-T binary-without-manpage` option (and other options to select the packages that you want to check).

Comment: didn't know about that, thanx.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to the accepted answer, it was interesting to learn about the existence of utility `manpage-alert`, part of the `devscripts` package, which is actually a shell script.

I tried to install `devscripts` but I got a prompt to install around 70MB of dependencies, so I skipped.

Downloading the `devscripts` deb package (`apt download devscripts`), extracting the deb and taking a closer look to `manpage-alert` script, the whole story "under the hood" is that this alert script runs the command:

`man -w -S 1:8:6 <file>`  (w=show location -S 1:8:6 limits man search in sections 1,8 and 6).

This operation is performed in all the files recursively under directories `/bin`, `/sbin`, `/usr/bin`, `/usr/sbin`, and `/usr/games`.

Moreover, redirecting `man` to `2>&1` and also redirecting to `>/dev/null`, if a file has a valid man page location nothing is printed, but if `man` complains  for a "no manual entry" then this message is printed.
Author of `manpage-alert` is further stripping `man` error message from "see man 7 undocumented for help" message and keeps only the first line = `No manual entry for xxxx`.

As a result, the following few lines will give a similar print of binaries missing man pages without installing devscripts package:

```
F=( "/bin/*" "/sbin/*" "/usr/bin/*" "/usr/sbin/*" "/usr/games/*" )
for f in ${F[@]};do 
  for ff in $f;do
    if ! mp=$(man -w -S 1:8:6 "${ff##*/}" 2>&1 >/dev/null);then 
       echo "$mp" |grep -v "man 7 undocumented" #man 7 undocumented is printed in a separate line.
    fi
  done
done
```

PS: `${ff##*/}` keeps only the command name stripping the path `/usr/bin/` or `/bin/` or whatever

Above can also run as one-liner:

```
gv@debi64:$ F=( "/bin/*" "/sbin/*" "/usr/bin/*" "/usr/sbin/*" "/usr/games/*" );for f in ${F[@]};do for ff in $f;do if ! mp=$(man -w -S 1:6:8 "${ff##*/}" 2>&1 >/dev/null);then echo "$mp" |grep -v "man 7 undocumented";fi;done;done

No manual entry for ntfsmove
No manual entry for ipmaddr
No manual entry for iptunnel
^C
```

PS: You can of course install `devscripts` since a lot of nice utilities / scripts are included. I just like to know what runs under the hood :-)

Comment: There are lots ofinteresting packages in devscripts, for e.g. dch, rmadison, wnpp-check and some others, just didn't know about this one. It's well worth it. I doubt it will be a bashscript as debian has been trying to remove bashisms and rely on plain shell scripts which are more easily from one xterm to another.

Comment: @shirish Taking a closer look, original `manpage-alert` script begins with `#!/bin/sh -e`